# Congratulations, you're no longer in Beta!

Tags: discussion, beta

**This site started private beta before July 2012, so it is no longer "beta", it is a full site by our definition**. We've removed the word "beta" from your site banner because we believe that you aren't really a beta site any more, even if you don't get ten questions per day.

[image: Banner that reads "Congratulations" in three-dimensional white text with red, yellow and blue confetti.]

What this means for you:

- the "Beta" is removed from your banner
- the site is moved to the "[Launched](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched)" sites list on Area 51 - which will also remove the A51 info box from the right sidebar
- retain beta reputation levels
- full-site elections will be delayed but will be scheduled eventually

This is the start of a process that we are already discussing internally and will be bringing to the network for public discussion once the plan is finalized. My hope is that this will mean the end of the monolith we currently refer to as "Graduation" in favor of a well-defined set of small targets to achieve the various elements that made up "Graduation".

I'm sure you have many questions, please feel free to ask and I'll answer what I can. It helps me out a lot if you can limit answers to focus on a single question/subject rather than asking a dozen questions in one answer.

Please feel free to [follow the MSE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta) for more background on this decision. You can ask questions either here or there; I'll try to keep up with all of them. Your mods also have some info, so they may be answering in my stead.

Thanks so much for your patience and stay tuned!

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations, community! After 9 years, PM.SE has graduated!

I'd like to take this space to share some of the trending questions around the graduation. This information is likely to be kept updated in the near future.

---

**Q:** Yey! But... wait... What does it mean? **What will change?**

**A:** Catija has explained on her post... take your time and visit it. If you're *really, really in a rush*, here's [the TL;DR version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/157692):

- have the "Beta" removed from their banner
- be moved to the "Launched" sites list on Area 51 - which will also remove the A51 info box from the right sidebar
- will retain beta reputation levels
- full-site elections will be delayed but will be scheduled eventually

---

**Q:** What about **reputations**? Will current community access be reduced / rep need increased for specific actions?

**A:** [No changes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331710/157692) Reputation and accesses will be kept as is for now.

---

**Q:** What about **mods**? Will they be kept?

**A:** It was answered above... you're in a really hurry, aren't you? Well, full site elections [will be scheduled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/157692) eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations! It is worth taking a step back and recognizing the incredible resource we've all built together, as a community. It provides answers to thousands of people a day with an active community comprised of more than 500 people. Total registered users is more than 25,000.

Can't wait to see what comes next!!