# Announcing an upcoming election

Tags: discussion

**Summary**: Project Management Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://pm.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **August 2**, as your "graduation" election (as a result of having [lost your beta label](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/856/congratulations-youre-no-longer-in-beta) a while back).

The timeline:

On July 26, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.

Starting on August 2, users can [nominate themselves](https://sound.stackexchange.com/election/1). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a second Meta post, so that potential moderators can answer them.

On August 9, if there are four or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for one more week. If at the end of this extension period there are still not four or more candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods) and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, [see the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-moderator-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-pa), but I doubt that will come up.)

If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on August 17 (or on the 24th, if we need to extend the nomination period and only get 4 or more candidates then).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: This post was a time-bound announcement that is now obsolete. It didn't generate any discussions that would represent accepted answers to long-tail questions, and future elections will generate new OPs. As a result, this  question is being closed but might be valuable to *not* delete as some of the comments related to SE implementations and limitations may be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The nominations for the election have been extended for another week (until August 16, 2021) as we need more candidates. Please consider helping the moderation team and helping with this site's "graduation" election, by nominating in [the election page](https://pm.stackexchange.com/election/1)!

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Can we (the community) each nominate a short list of other people to be considered for the election?

### There are Plenty of Good Candidates

Considering the relatively low level of interest in moderating the site (which is more emblematic of the business of our users than a lack of real interest) is there any rule or prohibition against nominating *others* besides ourselves for consideration?

There are a number of very active and experienced users on this site that could make valuable additions to the moderator team. While I would not want to be responsible for tapping a singular person to be given a diamond, I can easily think of 3-5 people who would make good additions to the moderation team, and could think of a few more names if needed.

Is there any reason I can't suggest them? The only reason I can think of myself is that nominating others might lead to hurt feelings that I suggested person X and left person Y off the list, but I'd like to think we're all adults and realize that we have to shortlist *someone* (or set of someones) if we want to present the community with both choice and additional voices.

Comment: The main reason is purely functional: our UI doesn't allow for nominating other users. If it were possible, though, those folks would need to _accept_ a nomination made by another user. With that in mind, I'd recommend reaching out to and encouraging those folks you'd nominate if the system allowed for it, potentially in chat — you would presumably do this even if the UI allowed for it, I think. I know it's probably not the answer you were looking for, but it's the best alternative we have available.