# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://pm.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Project Management has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Todd A. Jacobs]

[image: Tiago Cardoso]

[image: Thomas Owens]

Please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://pm.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6667395381854208).

Comment: Congratulations Todd, Tiago and Thomas! And thanks for volunteering!

Comment: *breaks into song* hear hear!!  Well done all!

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

Congratulations to everyone elected. Also, a special thank you to the staff who ran the election, and to the community members who voted!

### Of Course I Have More to Say!

First of all, I really appreciate the votes from the community. I'm glad that you feel that I'm doing a good job as moderator, and look forward to continuing to serve in that capacity.

I'd also like to congratulate Tiago, who has been a great fellow moderator during my previous tenure. I'm looking forward to continuing to work with you.

Of course, I can't write this section without welcoming [Thomas Owens](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/30/thomas-owens) to the team. On a personal level, I've found Thomas to have valuable points of view in many of the community discussions, and look forward to working with him as a moderator on PMSE.

#### If the Process Had Been Different

In one of my [previous meta posts](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/891/4271), I asked if we could nominate others. There are actually quite a few people who I think would also make great moderators here. I won't name names, but while I'm happy with the results of the election, I'm also sorry some of you didn't get your names into the hat. That's not because I think the current crop of moderators is lacking, or that the election didn't turn out well, but more because I think a wider variety of voices is generally a good thing.

That doesn't mean those people can't still do what they currently do, which is to vote, comment, and keep the site clean and efficient. It just means that I wish there was a better way to recognize non-diamond moderation activities other than as a general "thank you." Please know that your hard work has *not* gone unnoticed.

PMSE doesn't make heavy use of chat or meta, so this post may not be noticed by as many as it should. Still, I hope some of you see it, and know that you were thought of during and after the election process.